# Struts 2 and Websockets

Tags: struts, websocket

Is it possible to get Struts working with Websockets? On the .NET side, there is SignalR. I have been reading about Comet, jWebSocket, but can they be integrated with Struts? Or does one need to build an application from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSR 356](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=356), Java API for WebSocket, is on its way...

Until it arrives - there are several vendors providing WebSocket API in Java. [Kaazing](http://kaazing.com) (the company I work for) also supports JMS for messaging. [Here](http://demo.kaazing.com/demo/jms/java/)'s a live, hosted demo that you can try out.